# Зашифрованная переменная C++

Tags: http, c++, sql

Есть такая программа "Ларди Терминал". Скачал снифер, чтобы узнать, откуда она берет всю инфу, чтобы написать более расширенный аналог такой программы, но программа отправляет какую-то бурду и ее же принимает. Пытался расшифровать, но return 0; Насколько я понял, отправляется  переменная, потом шифруется  в MIME-кодировке. По моим догадкам, там отправляется какая-то SQL переменная. Если кто шарит, помогите, программа по зарез нужна!

Принятый программой текст:

> `CADPbekRs7GvyM1RKEstKs7Mz7NVMtQzUFJIzUvOT8nMS7dVKs/MS8kvL9Y1NDI1VLK347LxcQxy8bTj`

Comment: Речь про http://lardi-trans.com/terminal/ ?

Comment: Какой-то у вас набор слов прям, MIME, sql, return 0...

Comment: Да речь об этой программе!

Comment: "Пытался расшифровать, но return 0;" =)

Comment: "Пытался расшифровать, но return 0" - означает что расшифровка без результатна!

Comment: return 0 - это видимо сленг, к коду отношения не имеет ))
А вообще мне интересно, как ты пытался расшифровать...

Comment: Простым онлайн декодером.

Comment: Это нормальный BASE64, кодирует вот такие строки в cp-1251

     Пmй◄⌂▒ЇИНQ(K-*ОМП⌂U2Ф3PRHНKОOЙМK·U*ПМKЙ//Ц5425T⌂·г⌂сq♀rс⌂г

или KOI-8R (автоматически определителяется как наиболее вероятная)

     оmИ◄Ё╬╞хмQ(K-*нлоЁU2т3PRHмKнOилK⌂U*олKи//ж5425T╡⌂Ц╡Яq♀rЯ╢Ц

в других кодировках такая же галиматья. Кстати, первые 2 байта:

    0x08 0x00

явно не текст

@ltachi779, данные *какой природы* Вы ожидали увидеть? Пока данных для успешной расшифровки маловато...

Comment: @avp, а почему вы решили, что это именно base64?

Comment: Йомайо, или я идиот, или что такое переменная sql?!! Какое вообще переменная может иметь род? Переменная по сути это ж просто данные. Или я проснулся не в той вселенной где засыпал? =\

Comment: @dzhioev, во первых просто видно. И программы декодирования base64 (например base64 -d в убунту) эту строку нормально воспринимают (ни на что не ругаются). 

Далее смотрим кодировки русского языка (можно через браузер), но похоже это не он.

--

@Itachi779, что значит "тип переменной sql"? Я не понимаю. Откуда эти данные вообще взялись (какая была последовательность действий)?

Comment: @itachi779, скажите пожалуйста, что вы хотите видеть в итоге? что бл.ть по вашему "перевести в переменную"?

Comment: Уверяю вас, вы ничего там не прочтете. Почитал описание этой программулины, судя по всему там идея фикс - максимальная экономия траффика, а потому очень сильно сомневаюсь чтобы они данные гоняли в чистом. Там просто что-то зашифровано в бинарном виде и ВСЕ!!!

Comment: @avp Вы серьезно думаете, что это base64?

Comment: @rasmisha, а что тут думать-то? Base64 - обратимый алгоритм шифрования...

Comment: @Asen а при чем тут обратимый или не обратимый? Ключ от винды(без дефисов если) тогда тоже base64 )

Comment: base64 это метод кодирования, а не шифрования

Comment: Я особо не разбирался, но у них есть API http://api.lardi-trans.com/. Оно вам не подходит?

Comment: Да я сначала тоже думал что api и все проблемы решены НО! API разработан для управлением своими предложениями. А я хочу чтобы можно было просматривать предложения всех пользователей по определенном критериям поиска.

Comment: @rasmisha, приведенные в вопросе 80 байт

    CADPbekRs7GvyM1RKEstKs7Mz7NVMtQzUFJIzUvOT8nMS7dVKs/MS8kvL9Y1NDI1VLK347LxcQxy8bTj

могут быть чем угодно. Если их рассматривать, как кодировку BASE64, то закодировано 80 байт данных, начинающихся с 0x08, 0x00 ...

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что тут гадание на кофейной гуще. Программисты расшифровывают бинарник.

Answer (score 2):

Погуглил: `lardy terminal`

Нашел ссылку на [офф сайт](http://lardi-trans.com/terminal/), вот что там написано:

> Экономия интернет-трафика - 
> Все данные, передаваемые от сервера к "Терминалу" и от "Терминала" к серверу, архивируются.

Comment: так ты хочешь сказать что программа передает закодированную бинарку zip архива?

Comment: @Itachi779, попробуйте разные архиваторы. 

gunzip не съел.

Только, вряд ли это архив (60 байт). Просто какая-то компрессия (не gzip).

Comment: Я не понимаю что значит "компрессия (не gzip)";

Comment: @itachi779, при чем здесь zip-архив? что вы вообще мелете? вы вообще какое-то отношение к программированию имеете? данные перед передачей сжимаются и передаются на сервер, кроме того они имеют какой-то внутрениий формат, нечитабельный для человека, но который понимает сторона-приемник.

Comment: Ок. Но в папке с программой есть такая библиотека DelZip179.dll. Это о чем то говорит?

Comment: возможно это какая-то модификация зип-алгоритма. это может быть что угодно. с другой стороны вам никто не мешает использовать ту же длл для того чтоб его розархивировать

Comment: dll - скомпилированный код который выполняется процессором. ему до балды на чем вы пишете, делфи / с++. главное чтоб было скомпилировано именно под эту платформу (в вашем случае под windows)

Comment: Спасибо буду юзать!